# Use brave as the search engine in the Tor Browser

Tags: browser, tor, brave

Tor uses DuckDuckGo as it's default search engine. However, IMO brave gives far better search results and it's privacy is in-line with if not better than DuckDuckGo. Therefore I would like to use it instead.

However, Brave is not on the default list for Tor and while there is a Brave plugin Tor does not recommend using plugins. How do I configure Tor to use Brave as it's search engine without using a plugin.